# Jenkins push image to GCR

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Requirement is to build the image from docker and push the image to GCR(Google container Registry).
So I have installed the necessary plugins in Jenkins. Also, I have written jenkinsfile for this.

```
 withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'saProject', variable: 'GC_KEY')]){
     sh "gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file='$GC_KEY'"
 }
```

I am trying to access GCP like this but I am getting the below error.

`ERROR: Credentials 'saProject' is of type 'Google Service Account from private key' where` `'org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.FileCredentials' was expected`
`Finished: FAILURE`

I couldn't find what is the issue. Can anyone help to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Here is what we are doing:

```
environment {
        GCR_CRED = credentials('GCR_CRED')
        GCR_REPO = "gcr.io/${blahblah}"
    }

sh 'echo "$GCR_CRED" > abc.json'
sh 'docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat abc.json)" https://gcr.io'
sh "docker build . -t ${GCR_REPO}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
sh "docker push ${GCR_REPO}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
sh 'docker logout https://gcr.io'
```

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If yes can you please mark this as the answer.